# In Next.js 13 (App Router), how can I use Data Caching when not using fetch but directly calling the DataBase?

Tags: next.js

In the docs of Next.js 13, https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#data-cache, says that you can use data-cache in fetch in a server component to cache data.

I'm trying to do something similar, but instead of fetching, I want to do query the database.

```
export default async function Home() {

  const categorias = await getCategorias()

  return (
    <main className="flex">
      <ul>
        {categorias.map((categoria) => (
          <li key={categoria.ID}>
            <Link href={`/item/${categoria.ID}`}>{categoria.TITULO}</Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Exist any options to cache the data of `getCategorias`?

Comment: Struggling with this too

Answer (score 2):

When you go to production, your data will be cached by default. To control this behavior when not using [`fetch`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/fetch), you can use [Route Segment Config Options](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config) and React's [`cache`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#react-cache-function) function as they say on the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#fetching-data-on-the-server-with-third-party-libraries):

> In cases where you're using a third-party library that doesn't support or expose [`fetch`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/fetch) (for example, a database, CMS, or ORM client), you can configure the caching and revalidating behavior of those requests using the  [Route Segment Config Options](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config) and React's [`cache`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#react-cache-function) function.

> In the example below, the revalidate option is set to 3600, meaning the data will be cached and revalidated at most every hour.
> The React `cache` function is used to [memoize](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#request-memoization) data requests:

```js
import { cache } from 'react'
 
export const revalidate = 3600 // revalidate the data at most every hour
 
export const getItem = cache(async (id) => {
  const item = await db.item.findUnique({ id })
  return item
})
```

> Although the `getItem` function is called twice, only one query will be made to the database.

```js
// app/item/[id]/layout.js

import { getItem } from '@/utils/get-item'
 
export default async function Layout({ params: { id } }) {
  const item = await getItem(id)
  // ...
}
```

```js
// app/item/[id]/page.js

import { getItem } from '@/utils/get-item'
 
export default async function Page({ params: { id } }) {
  const item = await getItem(id)
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd go with https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#unstable_cache
Just notice it's not production ready yet.

from nextjs docs:

> unstable_cache is an experimental API for adding values to the Data Cache when the fetch API is not suitable. For example, when using database clients, CMS clients, or GraphQL.

And an example code from the docs as well:

```
import { unstable_cache } from 'next/cache'
 
export default async function Page() {
  const cachedData = await unstable_cache(
    async () => {
// Here you can enter the code that fetches your categories.
      const data = await db.query('...')
      return data
    },
    ['cache-key'],
    {
      tags: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
      revalidate: 10,
    }
  )()
}
```

So basically, it looks like unstable_cache can wrap calls to the DB, and assign keys that can later be invalidated on demand, or automatically using `revalidate`.

hope this helps.

Comment: Added brief explanation how this solves the problem. hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Now we can use [react-cache-function](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#react-cache-function) for these cases.
In this section of the documentation explain deeply the subject [fetching-data-on-the-server-with-third-party-libraries](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#fetching-data-on-the-server-with-third-party-libraries)